# How to use Newsletter module?

Tags: 7

I am using Newsletter module to send newsletter to all my registered users. I have created 2 lists 1.Blog and 2. Project (Have created templates for them as well). My questions are;

1. How to send only projects node in the project's list? (Does the fields in the templates are enough?)
2. The test mail just sends the [node: title] like tokens. What should I add to mail the contents of the node?

Thanks